# VHDL: Conditionally Instantiate Components using Generics

Tags: vhdl

I'd like to conditionally instantiate components using generics set on the command line.  I'd prefer to have a string as the generic (i.e. `fast` or `slow`) rather than a number.

I can't find any examples of this on stackOverflow so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Consider using enumeration types rather than strings for  this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of conditionally instantiating architectures of a component using generics.  The same code would work for instantiating different components:

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dut is
    generic (
         SPEED : string := "fast"
     );
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        start: in std_logic;
        done:  out std_logic);
    end entity dut;


architecture dutarch of dut is

    component delay is
        port (
            clk : in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            start: in std_logic;
            done: out std_logic
        );
    end component delay;
    begin
     d1g: if (SPEED = "fast") generate
          d1f : entity work.delay(fast)
           port map (
                clk     => clk,
                reset   => reset,
                start   => start,
                done => done
            );
        else generate
          d1s : entity work.delay(slow)
            port map (
                clk     => clk,
                reset   => reset,
                start   => start,
                done => done
            );

        end generate;
end architecture dutarch;
```